# How do I improve atrocious EF4 performance when enumerating an association?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-4

I'm working on movie database app using Entity Framework 4 (database first) and it is taking 30 seconds to load about 8,200 rows into a List.  There are three tables involved and when I use .Include(), performance degrades even more -- almost three minutes to load 8,200 rows.  This is painful.  Given I'm learning a lot of technologies at once, I'm hoping there is a simple fix.  Here are the details:

Table 1 - Videos

This is a large table with 31 columns about about 7,800 rows of videos.  It uses a Guid as its primary key.

Table 2 - ActorsVideos (a junction table)

This table has two columns: (1) VideoID column, and (2) ActorID column.  Both columns are Guid's and are foreign keys into the Video and Actor tables, respectively.  This table uses a composite primary key where both columns act as the primary key.  EF4 does not model this table; however, it creates a navigation property.  This table allows the user to assign any number of actors to a movie.

Table 3 - Actors

Has 16 columns about about 400 rows.  Again, the primary key is a Guid.

In the code, I'm reading about 10 columns in the Videos table and then I read columns from the associated Actors table.

The C# code looks something like this:

```
var videos = context.Videos
foreach (var video in videos)
{
    // retrieve 10 or so properties from 'video'

    if (video.Actors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var actor in video.Actors)
        {
            // retrieve some properties on the actor
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adding .Include("Actors") after context.Videos and, as stated above, performance went from terrible to horrific.

I've looked at the SQL that is generated with the Include and it's about 2K of text given the number of columns that are in the video table.

Do I have to split the video table using a Master/Detail pattern?  My next step is to cache the actors table and avoid the navigation/association property altogether.  Any other suggestions to make this faster?  It should run in less than 5-6 seconds in my opinion.

EDIT: The database is SQL Server CE 3.5.

Comment: Missing indexes in your database seem like a likely candidate for this sort of performance. At a guess, adding an index to column used as the 2nd value in your composite PK might help.

Comment: ...and indexes on all FK columns

Comment: SqlCe could be part of the problem, as well.

Comment: Also, minor note--you don't need to check count before looping through a non-null IEnumerable instance.

Comment: I would also look at changing key types to ``int`` from GUID. If you're not planning to store more than 4G entries, int will be probably be faster with SqlCE

Comment: Why don't you let SQL Server do the filtering instead of in-code? Then it only returns the rows you really need.

Comment: I added indexes before I posted.  Performance is still terrible.  Good suggestions though.  I'm going to try to push as much work up to the server as I can.

Comment: I'm getting close.  Using "var videos = from video in context.Videos" followed by "from actor in video.Actors", performance is excellent when I use select new.  Thanks to the suggestions to push the work to the server.  The only thing left to solve is how to quickly retrieve the list of videos that do *not* have actors (unknown actors really).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking Entity Framework to load a video along with all of it's actors, then you're doing the filtering in application code. Generally, you're pulling way more data than you need to. I would have SQL Server (or whatever DB you're using) pre-filter for you:

```
var videos = context.Videos;
var results = from video in videos
              where video.Actors.count > 10
              group video.Actors by video.VideoID into grouping
          select new
          {
              video.VideoID,
              video.Actors
          };

foreach (var group in results)
{
    foreach (var actor in group.Actors)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Loading ~8200 rows, along with their associated rows in the videos table should be extremely fast. I did some development at my job where I had to deal with a 70+ million row test data table with a 5 table join. This ran in something like half a minute.

But, the reason why it ran that much faster than what you're doing is because I was filtering *inside* of SQL Server. The equivalent "procedural" program using EF took several minutes because I was doing filtering AFTER I pulled the rows from the database.

Think of it this way: You're not only asking for every row in your database, but you're *pulling in data that you don't even need to multiple times*.

Comment: I understand this concept.  In testing the sample code, "video" doesn't exist in the select new context.  I'm going to play around with this to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [eager loading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx):

```
var videos = context.Videos.Include(v=>v.Actors);
foreach (var video in videos)
{
    foreach (var actor in video.Actors)
    {
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: Beware, that queries use deferred execution, which means that iterating multiple times executes queries multiple times as well. If you will be iterating multiple times use `.AsEnumerable()` and assign it locally prior to iterating.
Also, profiling the database to see which queries are being executed will help in determining what else you need to eagerly fetch. You may be possibly forcing EF to load unneeded entities.
If that's the case, then your query should only project (by using `Select(x=> new {...stuff you need... })`) the necessary data.

**EDIT**: According to [Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx), `Include()` can't be combined with projections, so in that case you'd need to write the query differently.

Comment: It's quite a bit worse than that. He's doing a minimum of two round trips for each video. It's worse with eager loading because then he's pulling ALL the associated data in each time he does a round trip as opposed to iff the video row satisfies his (application side) predicate.

Comment: Using Include() won't force it to go fetch the actors using a separate query for each video, it should get all videos and associated actors in one round-trip, using a join. Yes, it is a pretty big object graph, but if he really wants to iterate through the whole thing and doesn't need to filter anything out then it should be the fastest approach. Combining it with a projection to really only get the properties of videos and actors he needs I think would make it optimal.